# How to backup output of each pipe procedure?

Tags: pipe, backup

I'm using a pipe procedure for data analyzing every day:
`alias analyze='fetch_data | prog1 | prog2 | prog3 > result.txt'`
This script works well mostly, but it has about 1% probability to fail. As running it again and again is quite time consuming, I hope I can backup the result for each procedure, for example:

```
/tmp/2017-10-31-10am/fetch_data.txt
/tmp/2017-10-31-10am/prog1.txt
/tmp/2017-10-31-10am/prog2.txt
/tmp/2017-10-31-10am/prog3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the alias generate a directory in /tmp based on today's date, in the format `/tmp/YYYY-MM-DD-HH` (followed by am or pm), then save all of the intermediate output to separate files:

```
alias analyze='d=$(date +"/tmp/%Y-%m-%H%p"); mkdir "$d" && fetch_data | tee "$d/fetch_data.txt" | prog1 | tee "$d/prog1.txt" | prog2 | tee "$d/prog2.txt" | prog3 > "$d/result.txt"'
```

Or, broken across multiple lines:

```
alias analyze='
  d=$(date +"/tmp/%Y-%m-%H%p")
  mkdir "$d" && 
  fetch_data | tee "$d/fetch_data.txt" | 
  prog1 | tee "$d/prog1.txt" | 
  prog2 | tee "$d/prog2.txt" | 
  prog3 > "$d/result.txt"
  '
```

This relies on `date` to generate the directory name/template and the [`tee`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) utility to duplicate the incoming data to a file as well as pass it along the pipeline.

An example run (with made-up programs substituted for fetch_data & etc):

```
alias a='
  d=$(date +"/tmp/%Y-%m-%H%p")
  mkdir "$d" && 
  seq 10 | tee "$d/seq.out" | 
  head -6 | tee "$d/head.out" | 
  sed s/3/j/ | tee "$d/sed.out" | 
  tail -4 > "$d/result.txt"
  '
```

With the results:

```
$ ls /tmp/2017-10-19PM/
head.out  result.txt  sed.out  seq.out

$ cat /tmp/2017-10-19PM/seq.out
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ cat /tmp/2017-10-19PM/head.out
1
2
3
4
5
6

$ cat /tmp/2017-10-19PM/sed.out
1
2
j
4
5
6

$ cat /tmp/2017-10-19PM/result.txt
j
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what you’re asking. 
If you want to save the output from each program, do

```
fetch_data | tee f_d.txt | prog1 | tee prog1.txt | prog2 | tee prog2.txt | prog3 > result.txt
```

(I abbreviated `fetch_data.txt` to `f_d.txt` just for readability.) 
Wouldn’t `prog3.txt` be the same as `result.txt`?